# Non displayed content within <td> fills up space

Tags: html

If have a table like this one:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label style="display: none;">
            [...]
        </label>
        <label [...] />
    </td>
</tr>
```

The first label is not displayed as intended, but it fills up (invisible) space in the table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No it's not. It's something else - please post your actual HTML and if possible jsfiddle sample or a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a missing  tag around some text inside . Thanks!

Comment: Close the question by accepting your answer. Better write code in answer

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
<tr>
<td><label style="display: none;">[...]</label><label [...] /></td>
</tr>
```

So without any spaces at all between start and end td tag.